# Validate a TextBox before the _Change event is fired

Tags: string, validation, textbox, vb6

I've got a form that has 3 `TextBox` controls on it: stock code, quantity, certificate number. The stock code `TextBox` is set to focus automatically when the form is loaded.

I've also attached a bar code scanner to my PC, as the user wants to be able to either scan a bar code to populate the `TextBox`, or manually type the data in.

The labels being scanned contain two bar codes. One is a certificate number and the other a stock code.

The stock bar code has a prefix of "SBC/", whilst a certificate bar code is prefixed with "C/".

When the user scans a bar code, if the `TextBox` in focus is the stock code `TextBox`, then I want to run a check as below.

```
Private Sub txtStockCode_Change()

On Error GoTo errError1

If Len(txtStockCode.Text) >= 5 Then
    If bChangeCode Then
        If Left(txtStockCode.Text, 2) = "C/" Then
            msgbox "You have scanned the certificate barcode; please scan the stock barcode."
            txtStockCode.Text = ""
        Else
            bChangeCode = False
            txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "SBC/", "")
            txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "*", "")
        End If
    End If
End If

Exit Sub
```

Let's say the focus is currently on the stock code `TextBox`.

If the stock bar code is scanned, the following should happen:

- Stock code length is greater than 5
- Left 5 characters *do not* = "C/", so correct code has been scanned
- `TextBox` text value is updated to remove all * and the prefix of "SBC/"

E.g. "SBC/A12-TR0*" becomes "A12-TRO"

and

- Certificate number length is greater than 5
- Left 5 characters *do* = "C/", so incorrect code has been scanned
- `MsgBox` to user
- `TextBox` value is reset to ""

However, no matter which code is scanned into the stock code `TextBox`, the value is never validated.

E.g. "SBC/A12-TR0*" remains as "SBC/A12-TR0*" and "C/29760" remains as "C/29760"

As the validation code is the same in the certificate `TextBox`, the same pattern is repeated vice versa.

Why are my values not updating, or how can I validate the input before the `_Change` is fired?

**EDIT**

I've now changed my code to

```
Private Sub txtStockCode_Change

   If txtStockCode.Text <> "" Then
      txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "SBC/", "")
      txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "*", "")
   End If

End Sub
```

But it still displays the prefix of SBC/, yet is removing the two * characters (at the start and end of the barcode as is required for the scanner to read it as a barcode)

Comment: In your code, it looks like you are trying to remove the wrong prefix.

Comment: @BrianMStafford oops, typo. Corrected.

Comment: Somewhere else in code have you set `bChangeCode` to `True`?

Comment: @BrianMStafford Yes, on the form load event it is set to `True`

Comment: The issue is because the Change event is firing once for every character of the bar code.  The `bChangeCode` gets set to `False` and short-circuits your logic.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Right, I see what you mean. I took out the `boolean` check and you're right in that it did remove the prefix. Oddly though it still allowed the CERT numbers into the stock boxes and vice versa.

Comment: I would expect to see that behavior with your existing code.  You may have better luck moving the logic to the `Validate` event, though this would require programming your scanner to append a `Tab` key.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the barcode reader to return Enter key at the end of the scanned barcode and then use the Keypress event to check it and make your changes.

```
Sub txtStockCode_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    If KeyAscii = vbKeyReturn Then
        If Len(txtStockCode.Text) >= 5 Then
            If bChangeCode Then
                If Left(txtStockCode.Text, 2) = "C/" Then
                    msgbox "You have scanned the certificate barcode; please scan the stock barcode."
                    txtStockCode.Text = ""
                Else
                    bChangeCode = False
                    txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "SBC/", "")
                    txtStockCode.Text = Replace(txtStockCode.Text, "*", "")
                End If
            End If
        End If        
    End If
End Sub
```